# How to move all files including hidden files into parent directory via *

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

Its must be a popular question but I could not find an answer.

How to move all files via * including hidden files as well to parent directory like this:

```
mv /path/subfolder/* /path/
```

This will move all files to parent directory like expected but will not move hidden files. How to do that?

Comment: this question has a [duplicate at SU](http://superuser.com/questions/61611/how-to-copy-with-cp-to-include-hidden-files-and-hidden-directories-and-their-con), with an even more correct answer (not the accepted one though):  `cp -r /path/to/source/. /destination`

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive set of solutions on this in UNIX & Linux's answer to [How do you move all files (including hidden) from one directory to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6397/40596). It shows solutions in Bash, zsh, ksh93, standard (POSIX) sh, etc.

---

You can use these two commands together:

```
mv /path/subfolder/* /path/   # your current approach
mv /path/subfolder/.* /path/  # this one for hidden files
```

Or all together ([thanks pfnuesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192070/how-to-move-all-files-including-hidden-files-into-parent-directory-via/20192079?noredirect=1#comment30104778_20192079)):

```
mv /path/subfolder/{.,}* /path/
```

Which expands to:

```
mv /path/subfolder/* /path/subfolder/.* /path/
```

(example: `echo a{.,}b` expands to `a.b ab`)

Note this will show a couple of warnings:

```
mv: cannot move ‘/path/subfolder/.’ to /path/.’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot remove /path/subfolder/..’: Is a directory
```

Just ignore them: this happens because `/path/subfolder/{.,}*` also expands to `/path/subfolder/.` and `/path/subfolder/..`, which are the directory and the parent directory (See [What do “.” and “..” mean when in a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54900/143251)).

---

If you want to just copy, you can use a mere:

```
cp -r /path/subfolder/. /path/
#                     ^
#                     note the dot!
```

This will copy all files, both normal and hidden ones, since `/path/subfolder/.` expands to "everything from this directory" (Source: [How to copy with cp to include hidden files and hidden directories and their contents?](https://superuser.com/a/367303/204979))

Comment: The braces are just a short cut for `mv /path/subfolder/* /path/subfolder/.* /path/`, not strictly necessary to combine the two commands into one.

Comment: I get the following error: ``mv: overwrite `/path/.'? y
mv: cannot move `/path/subfolder/.' to `/path/.': Device or resource busy
mv: overwrite `/path/..'? y
mv: cannot move `/path/subfolder/..' to `/path/..': Device or resource busy``

Comment: @Dejan Just ignore it. `.` denotes current directory and `..` denotes `up` directory. You must have noticed that all other files are moved.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the braces shortcut won't work for all shells, but @chepner command I think it will

Comment: @Debiprasad Granted, it can be ignored. But it would be nice not to have to. I'd rather not have errors outputting from my bash script.

Comment: @ChrisHarrison In that case, there are many alternate answers.

Comment: "Just ignore the warning" may not always be a good idea. Right now I'm having a problem with a script in which I need to stop execution if any step fails - since this solution always causes an error, it kills my script. I need a way to determine if the mv command failed or not...

Comment: @MarioVilas agreed. I wrote "Just ignore the warning" in the context of the warnings for the `.` and `..` directories (current and one level up).

Comment: If you're inside the subdirectory: `mv ./{.,}* ..`

Comment: `{.[!.],}*` works fine as a pattern to match hidden and unhidden files excluding `.` and `..` but always returns itself as well even if there are some matching files. This seems to be a bug and can be worked around by setting `nullglob` (`shopt -s nullglob`). But if one does that one could set `dotglob` instead which seems favorable to me. Either should probably only be enabled temporarily.

Answer (score 32):

I think this is the most elegant, as it also does not try to move `..`:

```
mv /source/path/{.[!.],}* /destination/path
```

Comment: yeah I noticed it giving those error messages also, nice find.

Comment: I think this is a very good solution but it's kinda hard to remember that pattern

Comment: this would miss files like `..anything` or `...anything` etc. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438355/2351568 contains the correct regex for this problem. **||** but anyway using `shopt -s dotglob` is still the better solution!

Comment: @DylanB don't memorize it. remember that it matches whatever is in the curlybrackets, separated by commas. `{a,b}*` would find all files starting with a or b such as "anatomy" and "bulldozer". The second match is just an empty match, equivalent to `*`, and the first match is equivalent to `.[!.]`, where the group `[!.]` means a group NOT starting with a `.`. This means `.*` but not `..*`.

Answer (score 30):

> This will move all files to parent directory like expected but will
>   not move hidden files. How to do that?

You could turn on `dotglob`:

```
shopt -s dotglob               # This would cause mv below to match hidden files
mv /path/subfolder/* /path/
```

In order to turn off `dotglob`, you'd need to say:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: Very helpful. Wanted to find out more but shopt is a builtin so `man shopt` doesn't work and `help shopt` is very brief. But you can do `bashman () { man bash | less -p "^       $1 "; }` and then `bashman shopt` to read all about it straightforwardly. (Might have to hit n to jump down to the command if there are lines starting with shopt, as I found.)

Comment: this will also affect all other commands like `ls`.. thus not really what you'd want, probably

Answer (score 6):

Alternative simpler solution is to use `rsync` utility:

```
sudo rsync -vuar --delete-after --dry-run path/subfolder/ path/
```

<sup>Note: Above command will show what is going to be changed. **To execute the actual changes, remove `--dry-run`**.</sup>

The advantage is that the original folder (`subfolder`) would be removed as well as part of the command, and when using `mv` examples here you still need to clean up your folders, not to mention additional headache to cover hidden and non-hidden files in one single pattern.

In addition `rsync` provides support of copying/moving files between remotes and it would make sure that files are copied exactly as they originally were (`-a`).

The used `-u` parameter would skip existing newer files, `-r` recurse into directories and `-v` would increase verbosity.

Comment: Best solution ever! In my case I just removed the -u parameter, because I wouldn't like to update the root folder. Thanks

Comment: This is one of those commands where if you're not careful, you can really mess things up for yourself in linux, permanently. Please update your answer to include sudo before the rsync command, otherwise, users can easily get Permission Denied for mkdir, but the file deletions will nevertheless move ahead, thus, the rsync command will delete your entire directory you want moved, and do nothing else. You will lose your entire directory. Once you add sudo to your answer, this should probably be the accepted answer.  So the command should be: sudo rsync -vuar --delete-after path/subfolder/ path/

Comment: @JohnnyB Sorry about the inconvenience. I've added `sudo` and `--dry-run`, so people can test the changes before running the actual command in order to avoid any potential mess.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was a --dry-run option.  Good addition.  No need for apology.  This is excellent.

Answer (score 6):

By using the `find` command in conjunction with the `mv` command, you can prevent the `mv` command from trying to move directories (e.g. `..` and `.`) and subdirectories. Here's one option:

```
find /path/subfolder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -exec mv -n {} /path \;
```

There are problems with some of the other answers provided. For example, each of the following will try to move subdirectories from the source path:

```
1) mv /path/subfolder/* /path/ ; mv /path/subfolder/.* /path/
2) mv /path/subfolder/{.,}* /path/ 
3) mv /source/path/{.[!.],}* /destination/path
```

Also, 2) includes the . and .. files and 3) misses files like ..foobar, ...barfoo, etc.

You could use, `mv /source/path/{.[!.],..?,}* /destination/path`, which would include the files missed by 3), but it would still try to move subdirectories. Using the `find` command with the `mv` command as I describe above eliminates all these problems.

Answer (score 3):

Let me introduce you to my friend "dotglob".  It turns on and off whether or not "*" includes hidden files.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch a b c .hidden .hi .den
$ ls -a
. ..  .den  .hi .hidden a b c

$ shopt -u dotglob
$ ls *
a b c
$ for i in * ; do echo I found: $i ; done
I found: a
I found: b
I found: c

$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls *
.den  .hi .hidden a b c
$ for i in * ; do echo I found: $i ; done
I found: .den
I found: .hi
I found: .hidden
I found: a
I found: b
I found: c
```

It defaults to "off".

```
$ shopt dotglob
dotglob         off
```

It is best to turn it back on when you are done otherwise you will confuse things that assume it will be off.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this problem when I have to **copy all the files** (including `.` files) to a target directory **retaining the permissions** is: (overwrite if already exists)

```
yes | cp -rvp /source/directory /destination/directory/
```

`yes` is for automatically overwriting destination files, 
`r` recursive, 
`v` verbose, 
`p` retain permissions.

Notice that the **source path is not ending with a `/`** (so all the files/directory and . files are copied)

**Destination directory ends with `/`** as we are placing contents of the source folder to destination as a whole.

Comment: While `yes` is an awesome command to use if you want to override destination files, that is not always desired. Only use it if you are sure you want to do this. Also, is there an difference between `yes | cp ...` and `cp -f ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this is still sought after in 2024. An alternative in BASH is use copy and then delete the source destination if required. No need for regex or modifying bash script options. Here is the code:

```
cp -arfv source/. desination #Note use of /.
rm -rfv source/*
```

Note the following:

1. We are using `/.` instead of `/*` to copy all folders/files, subfolders/files and hidden folders/files
2. `-arfv` means Archive, Recursive, Force and Verbose
3. Delete the folder after copying

My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```sh
for I in $(ls -A dir)
do
mv dir/$I newDir
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the **subfolder**
run `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} .. \;`