# How to copy without getting prompt for overwrite (overwrite all) all hidden files, folders and subfolders from one folder to anotherin linux?

Tags: linux, centos7, overwrite, cp

I am trying to copy everything (hidden files, folders and subfolders) from
`/home/old` to `/home/new`

I'm trying,

```
cp -r /home/old/.* /home/new

cp -r -f /home/old/.* /home/new
```

In both cases it prompts for the overwrite confirmation, I tried `A` instead of `Y` to fast the process but if doesn't works. Since I have many files I am just tired of pressing `y`

Any commands to overcome this? It is a `centOS 7`, and I am just connecting to the `VM` through `ssh`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192070/how-to-move-all-files-including-hidden-files-into-parent-directory-via then https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-from-one-directory-to-another/6397#6397

Comment: Looks like "yes|cp -rf " command works but it stopped at some point and still waiting! @
Apple BS